# Problem in make a date input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make a date input masked (hidden) without using a plugin, as followed:

**Formating:** `YYYY/MM/DD` = showing in the input as => `____/__/__`

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
$('.date_input').delegate("input.date:text", 'keyup', function () {
    //var dateMMDDYYYRegex = '^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$';
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{3,3}/g).join("/").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
});
```

[Example of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/CMUSD/1/)

Comment: Are the 3KB of the [jQuery mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) that much? If, yes, you could explore its [source code](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js) to see how it is implemented. But honestly reinventing wheels is not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to use the plugin. Please help me in simple code.

Comment: as you can see in the source code of the plugin there is no simple code to achieve this in a reliable way.

Comment: I used this plugin, this plugin has a lot of code. can be reached to target by a code simpler and smaller. Please help me!?

Comment: sorry I have already expressed my opinion on the subject. Hopefully someone else will want to help you reinvent the wheel. Personally I don't want to teach people bad practices.

Comment: Please give me a simpler sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.date_input').delegate("input.date:text", 'keypress', function (e) {
    var char = getChar(e || window.event);
    if (char != "/")
    {
        this.value += "_";
        return false;
    }
});

function getChar(event) {
  if (event.which == null) {
    return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) // IE
  } else if (event.which!=0 && event.charCode!=0) {
    return String.fromCharCode(event.which)   // the rest
  } else {
    return null // special key
  }
}


//You can replace getChar with the jQuery equivalent.
```

Comment: Do right use of your code? => http://jsfiddle.net/CMUSD/3/ i want this format(Regex) `YYYY/MM/DD`